# PING REQUEST TO HOST ONLY SUCCESFUL RIGHT AFTER I DO TRACERT TO THE SPECIFIC HOST?

Tags: networking

Our Company has a VPN connection  provided by the ISP in our country , I can Traceroute to a Remote host  on another site connected to the VPN  but I cant ping to it. The ping command works to hosts on remote site only for a short while right after I do the traceroute to the particular host. Why is it that the ping command only successful right after the tracert command is excueted??

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, this sounds like its potentially Proxy ARP? I would check to see whether or not the Traceroute is temporarily populating your ARP table, allowing the ping to work. Just because you can't ping a device right off the bat doesn't mean its not reachable.

Comment: Hey Ogee my arp table doesn't change after traceroute. The ping works after the trace route to the  ip however. It then stops pinging after I try to trace route to other IPs. Could there be any other issues  I can look into??